# Most efficient way to replace occurance in string with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

I am working on replacing environment variables with values in `Ruby`, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I have a `JSON` feed that I am parsing, which looks like this: `%MY_SERVER/json/data/mydata?someparameter` and another that looks like `%MY_OTHER_SERVER/json/data/mydata?somethingdifferent=thisorthat`

Each of the servers has a different `URL` that needs to be input. I have looked around and have seen things talking about using `replace` or looking for a specific pattern, but I don't think that is the most effective way.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or offer some advice on the best way to accomplish my task?

Comment: The first advice is to formulate your question clearly. What is the problem, what have you tried, what don't you like about your approach, what do you want?

Comment: What is the problem: " I am working on replacing environment variables with values in Ruby" What have your tried: "I have looked around and have seen things talking about using replace or looking for a specific pattern" What do you want? "Most efficient way to replace occurance in string with Ruby?" 

The answers to your question are there, you just have to read :)

Comment: Yeah, but you missed one: "What don't you like?" :)

Comment: Lol... Touche... I want something more dynamic. I have about 6 different servers that will need URL's and I don't want to have to hard code each one.

Comment: Also, "I've looked around" implies that you don't have it working. First make it work. Then you worry about efficiency :)

Comment: Well, I do have it working. Sort of. I hard coded specific variables and URL's, but there are now more, and I'm looking for a more dynamic approach. I don't want to have to recode every time there is an update

Comment: What do you need to replace? the SERVER_NAME?

Comment: Yes, `%MY_SERVER` AND `%MY_OTHER_SERVER` OR `%YET_ANOTHER_SERVER`. They are all formatted similarly, with a `%` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the dynamic approach you seek:

```
urls = [
  '%MY_SERVER/json/data/mydata?someparameter',
  '%MY_OTHER_SERVER/json/data/mydata?somethingdifferent=thisorthat'
  ]

name_regex = /(%\w+)/

ENV['%MY_SERVER'] = 'http://google.com'

replaced = urls.map do |s|
  s.gsub name_regex do |env_name|
    if ENV[env_name]
      ENV[env_name] # replace
    else
      env_name # leave it untouched
    end

    # or, the same thing, but shorter
    # ENV[env_name] || env_name
  end
end

puts replaced
# >> http://google.com/json/data/mydata?someparameter
# >> %MY_OTHER_SERVER/json/data/mydata?somethingdifferent=thisorthat
```

You just need to scan your input string and find all things that look like a placeholder. Luckily, your strings have them clearly formatted. Then you just supply values in your `ENV`. If a value for placeholder is missing, it won't be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for an efficient way to do

```
myString = "%MY_SERVER/json/data/mydata?someparameter"
myString.gsub!("%MY_SERVER",  ENV['MY_SERVER'])
```

And I think this is the best way to do it. 
I think using gsub is faster than using

```
myString["%MY_SERVER"] = ENV['MY_SERVER']
```

while

```
myString.replace
```

would replace the whole string, you don't want to use this.